# Project Euler no. 17: Counting letters to write the numbers from 1 to 1000

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge, numbers-to-words

I'm very new to programming and am admittedly embarrassed sharing my code for critique. This code works and produces the correct answer to the [Project Euler Problem 17](https://projecteuler.net/problem=17), which asks how many letters there are when the numbers from one to one thousand are written out in words (excluding spaces and punctuation).

I was hoping I could get some critique on how to make it less ugly and more streamlined, or even approach the problem from a totally new angle so I can better learn from this solution.

```
# the final list that holds the string lengths
addList = [] 

# dictionary holding integer:corresponding word pairs
numbersDict = { 
0:"zero",
1:"one",
2:"two",
3:"three",
4:"four",
5:"five",
6:"six",
7:"seven",
8:"eight",
9:"nine",
10:"ten",
11:"eleven",
12:"twelve",
13:"thirteen",
14:"fourteen",
15:"fifteen",
16:"sixteen",
17:"seventeen",
18:"eighteen",
19:"nineteen",
20:"twenty",
30:"thirty",
40:"forty",
50:"fifty",
60:"sixty",
70:"seventy",
80:"eighty",
90:"ninety"
}

### There has to be an easier way to do all this below ###

def numberLetters(num):

    letters = ""

    if 0 < num <= 20:
        letters += numbersDict[num]

    if 21 <= num <= 99:
        a,b = divmod(num, 10)
        if b == 0:
            letters += numbersDict[a*10]
        else:
            letters += numbersDict[a*10] + numbersDict[b]

    if 100 <= num <= 999:
        if num % 100 == 0:
            letters += numbersDict[int(num / 100)] + "hundred"
        else:
            digit = int(num / 100)
            num = num - digit * 100
            if 0 < num <= 20:
                letters += numbersDict[digit] + "hundredand" + numbersDict[num]
            if 21 <= num <= 99:
                a,b = divmod(num, 10)
                if b == 0:
                    letters += numbersDict[digit] + "hundredand" + numbersDict[a*10]
                else:
                    letters += numbersDict[digit] + "hundredand" + numbersDict[a*10] + numbersDict[b]
    if num == 1000:
        letters += "onethousand"

    return letters

for i in range(1,1001):
    addList.append(len(numberLetters(i)))
print(sum(addList))
```

Comment: Did you look on the project Euler answer forums? There's probably a bunch of really clean Python implementations there. Since your answer works, you should be able to view them.

Comment: thanks @michaelsnowden, I didn't even think of that. Will do going forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the repetitive logic in the code to handle numbers greater than a hundred, the solution is not bad.  There are many observations that could lead to improvements, though.

- You don't need to build the strings themselves; you just need to sum their lengths.  In particular, since strings are immutable, `+=` is relatively costly.  (Your solution is still fast enough, though.)
- The challenge never requires you to treat `0` as `"zero"`.  You can therefore simplify some logic by mapping `0` to an empty string.
- The ranges `0 < num <= 20`, `21 <= num <= 99`, `100 <= num <= 999`, and `num == 1000` are mutually exclusive.
- You can reduce repetition by using recursion.

### Solution

```
numbers_dict = {
    n: len(word) for (n, word) in {
        0: "",
        1: "one",
        2: "two",
        3: "three",
        4: "four",
        5: "five",
        6: "six",
        7: "seven",
        8: "eight",
        9: "nine",
        10: "ten",
        11: "eleven",
        # ...
        90: "ninety",
    }.iteritems()
}

def num_length(n):
    if n <= 20:
        return numbers_dict[n]
    elif n < 100:
        ones = divmod(n, 10)
        return numbers_dict[10 * tens] + num_length(rest)
    elif n < 1000:
        hundreds, rest = divmod(n, 100)
        return num_length(hundreds) + len("hundred") + (
            len("and") + num_length(rest) if rest else 0
        )
    else:
        thousands, rest = divmod(n, 1000)
        return num_length(thousands) + len("thousand") + num_length(rest)

print(sum(num_length(n) for n in range(1, 1001)))
```

You could also use `numbers_dict` for memoization:

```
def num_length(n):
    if n in numbers_dict:
        return numbers_dict[n]
    elif n < 100:
        tens, rest = divmod(n, 10)
        numbers_dict[n] = numbers_dict[10 * tens] + num_length(rest)
        return numbers_dict[n]
    elif n < 1000:
        hundreds, rest = divmod(n, 100)
        return num_length(hundreds) + len("hundred") + (
            len("and") + num_length(rest) if rest else 0
        )
    else:
        thousands, rest = divmod(n, 1000)
        return num_length(thousands) + len("thousand") + num_length(rest)
```